# Wait until all child components are bind to DOM | AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have a component in AngularJS 1.7.2 with few nested components:

```
| parent
| - child
| - - child1
| - - child2
```

In the parent component, I want to get **child1** component, where template begins with `<div id="child-1">` and add event listeners. For example (parent component):

```
$ctrl.$onInit = () => {
  $element.find('#child-1').addEventListener()
};
```

The problem is **$element.find('#child-1')** is **undefined**, because this component (child1) is not linked to DOM yet.

Is there any way how to wait until all child elements are bind to DOM?

Thanks!

Comment: In general the child component should add its own event listeners and communicate those events to parent components with expression binding. Use `&` in the bindings property of the child component. See, [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Answer (score 0):

You can use from this code:

```js
controller('paret',function($scope,Service,){
  Service.then(function(Data){
        $scope.data = Data;
  })
})
.controller('childOne',function($scope){
  $scope.$watch('Data', function() {
       console.log($scope.data);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the $timeout service to add the event last on the callstack, which will invoke the event after the components are rendered.

Try it like this

```
$ctrl.$onInit = () => {
  $timeout(function(){ 
    $element.find('#child-1').addEventListener(); }
    , 0);
};
```